# Is there a way to change the Doxygen term Modules in the tree and in the right pane pages to something else?

Tags: module, doxygen

I am using Doxygen groups and therefore see them listed in the Doxygen navigation tree under Modules, as expected. My project is documenting integration using Zend modules and therefore Doxygen Modules and the Zend modules tend to overload the term modules and make it confusing for the readers. My question is: is there a way, preferably an automated way, to change the Doxygen term Modules in the tree and in the right pane pages to something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've sucessfully changed the word 'Modules' in the past, but I've only ever needed to do this for the top-of-page tabs, and not the navigation tree.  The method I used than may also work for you:

- You need a fresh Layout file.
  Generate one with `doxygen -l layoutfilename.xml`
- Locate the line containing `type="modules"`
- Change the  `title` entry from `""` to `"Your Word"` - I used `"Index"`
- Specify the replacement layout file in you doxyfile.

Comment: Yes, this method worked exactly for what I want to do. It changed the term Modules in the navigation tree.

Comment: @IncaRoads Great. In which case it is etiquette to accept the answer by clicking on the green tick.  An upvote to indicate 'useful' would be nice too.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I clicked the tick but my lack of reputation doesn't allow me to upvote!

Comment: Do you happen to know if the term 'package' on the namespace can be overridden? I only seem to be able to name them collectively.

Answer (score 0):

After you did like the suggestion above.
If you want to manually replace it for PDF file that generates from latex you can open refman.tex go to `%--- Begin generated contents ---` and change to something like this:
(Note that I marked the lines you should edit with <========)

```
%--- Begin generated contents ---
\chapter{Main Page}
\label{index}\hypertarget{index}{}\input{index}
\chapter{Index Index} <========
\input{index} <========
\chapter{Index Documentation} <========
\input{whatever was here before}
%--- End generated contents ---
```

After that go to modules.tex and change the filename to index.tex (for this example).

Comment: Looks to me that the question is more about the HTML output than the LaTeX output.

Comment: @albert I came here looking to change it for both, and found this answer very helpful.

Comment: @ZackKnopp One always has to be careful when changing things in respect to "names" for the HTML / LaTeX it is best is always to look at the layout file (`doxygen -l ...`) and the header / footer files (`doxygen -w ...`, for the LaTeX header / footer in the doxygen master some big changes have been made regarding flexibility).

Comment: @albert True, I tried that first but didn't find any way to override every instance of the use "Class" in the latex document. My use case is we're building documentation for technicians on how a component operates and we don't want programmer vocabulary in the document.

Comment: @ZackKnopp I'm asking after 6 months, did you found a solution?

Comment: @Frighi I used Cheeseminer's solution to change most of the instances of the word "Class" and then I used dolev ben's answer to change the one or two that were still leftover, by changing the tex file before generating PDF. Although, there may be a better way to do it now.